# How to make awesomewm textclock reflect timezone change?

Tags: arch-linux, awesome, timezone, clock

I am using the `awful.widget.textclock` widget to display the time in Awesome WM on Arch Linux, and I am using a program called `tzupdate` to automatically update my system time according to geolocation periodically.

I travel frequently, so I thought it would be nice to automate this.  However, the textclock widget does not change the time unless I restart Awesome (or relog/restart).  Is there something I could add in the lua script to make the widget refresh the timezone?

`tzupdate` is working fine.  I have it on a `systemd` timer that updates the timezone every five minutes.  The system's timezone is successfully changed in this way.  The output of `timedatectl` immediately shows the updated timezone, and the output of the date command correctly displays the correct updated local time.

However, as noted above, Awesome fails to notice this timezone change until I restart (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) or logout.

Comment: What settings are you using for `awful.widget.textclock`?  Does something like this `mytextclock = awful.widget.textclock("%A %d %B %H:%M ")` work?

Comment: I am using `awful.widget.textclock("%a %b %d, %H:%M:%S", 1)`.  I tried the string you gave me but it didn't change anything.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/Asido/AwesomeWM/blob/master/lib/awful/widget/textclock.lua.in) the default timer value is 60 seconds.  Does it update after 60 seconds?

Comment: The default value is 60 seconds, but the second argument in my call to the widget sets the timer to 1 second.  Also, waiting for a full 60 seconds does not result in the clock updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an updated `textclock.lua` widget that responds to timezone changes at runtime.  I replaced the file `/usr/share/awesome/lib/awful/widget/textclock.lua`.  I also installed the `luatz` module from [this github repo](https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz) and moved the `luatz` folder to `/usr/share/lua/5.2/luatz` so that the `lua` `require` function finds it automatically.

/usr/share/awesome/lib/awful/widget/textclock.lua:

```
local setmetatable = setmetatable
local os = os
local textbox = require("wibox.widget.textbox")
local capi = { timer = timer }
local luatz = require("luatz")
local tzcache = require("luatz.tzcache")

--- Text clock widget.
-- awful.widget.textclock
local textclock = { mt = {} }

--- Create a textclock widget. It draws the time it is in a textbox.
-- @param format The time format. Default is " %a %b %d, %H:%M ".
-- @param timeout How often update the time. Default is 60.
-- @return A textbox widget.
function textclock.new(format, timeout)
    local format = format or " %a %b %d, %H:%M "
    local timeout = timeout or 60

    local w = textbox()
    local timer = capi.timer { timeout = timeout }
    timer:connect_signal("timeout", function() 
        tzcache.clear_tz_cache()
        w:set_markup(os.date("!"..format, luatz.time_in())) 
    end)
    timer:start()
    timer:emit_signal("timeout")
    return w
end

function textclock.mt:__call(...)
    return textclock.new(...)
end

return setmetatable(textclock, textclock.mt)
```